# Export a JavaFX project in eclipse to a runable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-11, runnable-jar

I need to send a project made by JavaFX SDK 16 and Java SE-15 using Eclipse to my friends, but when I try to export it, i'm getting surprised that Eclipse doesn't insert the VM arguments to the exported file :
[image]

and as you know since JavaFX SDK 10, JavaFX libraries are not anymore part of the Java SE, so we need to tell Eclipse where to find them by VM arguments, in short words, these VM arguments are really important to run my program.

I already know that I can insert those arguments while using prompt command to open it, but is there a more simple way? just by clicking on the exported file ?

Comment: You can create a start script that execute your program with arguments.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply, may i ask you if you have any tutorial for that

Comment: If you using windows look for creating batch files, if you using Linux/Unix look for creating shell scripts. Then put the content from commandline into those script

Comment: @Reporter I think the OP wants a clickable jar

Comment: @c0der Ist just an alternative way, because at the moment nobody has an solution.

Comment: Thank you, i think i'm just gonna start using IntelliJ, instead of Eclipse

Comment: How is shifting to Eclipse going to help ?

Comment: with intellij IDE we can export it with no issue, the problem is with Eclipse and i beleive Netbeans

Comment: Did _export it with no issue_  using IntelliJ as Javafx application ? or as Swing application with an embedded JavaFx component ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are trying to do something that does not make any sense. Runnable jars are not a proper distribution format for JavaFX applications for various technical reasons. The way to go is having a look at jpackage. That's the proper way of dealing with distribution nowadays. Otherwise your are just banging your head against a wall.

Here is a good summary of all the options you have: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68823040/4262407

Comment: thank you, you are right, it looks the better option is jpackage, i create a new thread for that : https://stackoverflow.com/q/68871952/16581317

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem 5 years ago (I use netbeans IDE, so I don't know if it works in eclipse, but I think yes), and I cant find a good way to do this.
Instead, I created one Swing application, and put all code of JavaFX inside.
You could see how I do in
[this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm) from Oracle.