# JavaFX : Jar Could not find or load main class main.Launcher

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, executable-jar

I wrote a JavaFX application with **JavaFX version 15.0.1**.

I'm using **IntelliJ IDEA** and all is working fine since I execute my code from IntelliJ.

Now I want to deploy the application building the Jar and creating an Executable.

I already know that there are some issues with versions after Java 8 because the packaging is not included anymore.

I searched a lot and found some useful stuff here on StackOverflow and on YouTube, following all the guides step by step.

I also found a video of a guy that uses my same JavaFX version, and IntelliJ to build the Jar, and at the end, he simply double-click on the created Jar and the application runs smoothly and with no errors.

That's my actual setup :

I set up the **Launcher.java** class to bypass the Main.java problem like in the guides.

```
package main;

import main.Main;

public class Launcher
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args){Main.main(args);}
}
```

I **built the project** and then in **artifact** I created a new one *based on modules* and added the **.dll** files from my JavaFX SDK.

[image: Artifact Setup]

After that, I **built the project** once again, and I went to : Build -> Build Artifacts and Build.

After this process, my **out** directory seems like this :

[image: Out Directory]

And in artifacts -> MenuManager_jar there is my **MenuManager.jar** file.

[image: MenuManager.jar File]

After that, as I saw in the guides, I can simply double click on it, or run it with :  *java -jar MenuManager.jar*, and it should run my application.

But after I double click, nothing happens, even if I run from console, with this command :

```
java -jar MenuManager.jar
```

or even

```
java --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar MenuManager.jar
```

it shows this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main.Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.Launcher
```

So after that, I decided to look for the *Launcher.class* file myself.

And that is present in my Jar opened as zip :

[image: Jar/main content]

Obviously out of the "main" directory in the jar there are all the dependencies/libraries :

[image: Jar Content]

I looked for posts/videos/guides/packaging tools, but I can't find a way to create this Jar or Executable for my Project. This process creates the Jar in the right way, but it seems I'm not able to run it for some reason.

I need help with this last step.

Comment: Please [don't upload images of code and error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).  You can edit the question to replace the images with text.

Comment: For building, I recommend using a build tool (e.g. maven or possibly gradle) rather than the artifact manager in the IDE.  IDEs have good integration with build tools, so you don't need to run the build tool externally if you don't want to. For distribution, I recommend creating a native installer using [`jpackage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818710/multi-module-javafx-maven-project-packaging-issue/68823040#68823040)  rather than a jar.  More info is available in the [runtime images section](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) of the openjfx docs.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To @jewelsea : It's my first post, so I'm not able to put Images in my text. Everytime I try to add one, it says I have to upload it, I will be able to put it in post after I get some interactions with the site I guess.

Comment: @rhagee I think you misunderstood.  The request was not to include images of text but instead put the text in the question as text.  Please see the link I posted.

Comment: @jewelsea Oh yes! Thank you, I'm sorry it's my first post and I didn't know that was a problem doing it. Btw I found out the fix myself! Appreciate your help!

Should I fix the post anyway?

Comment: If you have time to improve the question in a way that may help others, then do that.  Even with an accepted answer, a better written question helps other readers.

Comment: @jewelsea I edited the question, is it fine now?

Comment: @rhagee yes, it is much better now. I also inlined the remaining images of the IDE configurations (which are OK to leave as images).  I also upvoted your posts which should give you enough reputation to add images to future posts, if needed, in the future.

Comment: please can you share links for guide ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Found out myself the way to fix it!

I had some other **external libraries** imported in my project over the standard **JavaFX jar**.

It was a specific **mysql** library version imported as Jar.

It probably had some problems being built in artifact, I still don't know the reason, maybe it was a version problem or incompatibility.

After **replacing** it with another Library or **removing** it, the **jar** built fine and I'm able to run my appliation even double-clicking.

#### Suggestions

What I suggest to people with same problem or that want to start a JavaFX application and knows that they are going to create a **jar** is that :

- After importing a new Library try to build the artifact so you won't have some suriprises after using it and building.
- If the library is making the final **jar** not working, try to replace it with a similar one, or try to find out if there is a different version of the library.
- Since the start of the project try to **build** and **build artifact** every time you make some big changes to be able to track the problem faster.