# How to create a java executable and installer

Tags: java, gitlab, executable-jar

Im doing a java desktop app for school.
Been working on it since october and its almost completed.
Now, to be evaluated,I need do put on my git repo some installer that, well, installs the app.

Im not sure how to do this.
Im using IntelliJ, and as of now, i managed to create a java executable (.jar). The .jar file works fine.
Now, im not sure on what do do next(?) Sending the .jar file to my repo is enough? Probably not.
What I was thinking is uploading to my repo some installer that installs my .jar file.

Does this make any sense? If so, how could I do it?

Comment: What is your purpose of creating installer? If you want to run your app on other members PCs in your class, just sending out the jar file is enough. Double-clicking it would start the application and no need to install. Adding that jar file to the repository would have little meanings since people who can access the repo can build the app themselves and no need to access your jar file directly. Creating installer and want to distribute them as (something like) 'install-able application', try searching with the word 'jpackage'.

Comment: You can check Java Installer Builders like - https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have not seen the link @Vini sent me yet, but regarding the other too comments : i have already the executable, so thats not really the problem. I really need the installer, because thats part of the evaluation, sending the .jar file is not enough

Comment: Historically, there was no "standard" installer configuration is defined in Java, so if it is your situation, you should determine how and what you should create and deliver. Normally, on Windows systems, installers are packed into exe or msi, on Linux they are in rpm or deb format. Depending your target system and installer package format, tool for creating installer can vary. If you are OK for going with newest JDK, I recommend you to use jpackage, while it is standard tool to create installer, and included in latest JDK distributions. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68872016/4472711

Comment: If you can pay some money for proprietary installer-creating-tools, you can go that way and you can receive technical support by your contract.